# Forwarding stream from MediaStream object

Tags: node.js, redirect, webrtc, forwarding, mediastream

I have obtained a MediaStream object from using the simple-peer API to create a peer-peer connection, API -> https://github.com/feross/simple-peer
The code section that receives the audio stream and plays it on the video tag is

```
 peer.on('stream', function (stream) {
    console.log(stream);
    let video = document.querySelector('video')
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)
    video.play()
  })
```

The print statement that is obtained is https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYp1Z.jpg
I have then looked onto the API methods found, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream.

I am seeking help to know if I can push the stream data to another port on the same machine. i.e, redirect received RTP packets to port x on the same machine instead of playing it on the video tag? I can't use a socket, since it will pass through the whole object. I need a way to continuously redirect all received data.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could use another peer connection? See [webrtc samples](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/multiple-relay/).

Comment: Redirect to where, for what?